# Sync Logfiles Online in Real Time

Tags: boot, logs, rsync, synchronization

*Background:* I have a smart home device (roborock) running linux. For some reason it triggers factory resets every odd weak, presumably during reboots. I need to find out why and how to prevent it.

*Questions:* On factory resets, all logs are wiped clean. I need find a way to read the logs to be able to prevent future automatic factory resets. What is the easiest way to make sure logs (as early as possible during bootup) are synced online (e.g. on an ftp, or any other means).

Comment: I don't know what logging facility your Linux uses, but on a system with `syslogd` (or equivalent), I would set it up to log to some other host than to the local host.  That way you would automatically get the logs stored elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, that sounds promising. it does syslogd. I'll see if i find out to set another host

Comment: Ideally, a Linux user (i.e. not me) would answer and let us know how to configure `syslogd` to log to another host.